# convert python function to Javascript/node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

trying to simulate similar behavior of a python function with node.js.

Here is the python function:

*Input (for both of the function):*

```
(9x11)JHASGJHAYGGSDFLRAAAA(16x7)ABCDEFG
```

```
def evaluate_expression(sub_string):
    var re = require('re')
    regex = r'^([(](\d+)[xX](\d+)[)])?'
    prog = re.compile(regex)
    op = prog.match(sub_string)
    print('in evaluate exp', sub_string)
    expression_list = list(op.groups())
    # print(expression_list)
    str_len = int(expression_list[1])
    itr = int(expression_list[2])
    endindex = op.end()
    return str_len, itr, endindex-1
```

*Output:*

```
5 9 11
```

in JS i have tried so far:

```
evaluate_expression = (sub_string)=>{
    const a =/^([(](\d+)[xX](\d+)[)])?/g;
    const b = sub_string.match(a);
    // console.log(sub_string)
    let extratkted = b[0].split("x");
    return {
      str_len:extratkted[0].split("(")[1],
      itr:extratkted[1].split(")")[0],
    endpoint:extratkted.length+extratkted.length+extratkted.length-2
  }

 }
```

*Output:*

```
{str_len:9,itr:11,endpoint:4}
```

where Expected output: `{str_len:5,itr:9,endpoint:11}`

Comment: it seem you assign values in wrong order. In Python you use `[1]` and `[2]` but in Javascript you use different order `[1]`, `[0]`. In Python you have `endindex-1` but in JavaScript you do something similar to `endindex-2`

Comment: because of the `expression_list = list(op.groups())` in python this one gives different result than `let extratkted = b[0].split("x");` in js. what is your thought on this?

Comment: if you get wrong order in result then change order in code to get correct result.

Comment: i guess, you are right, let me recheck it with few more inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem you have good values but they are assigned in wrong order.

In Python you use `[1]` and `[2]` but in Javascript you use different order `[1]`, and `[0]`. If you assign values in different order then you should get correct result.

---

In Python you have `endindex-1` but in JavaScript you do something similar to `endindex-2` so you get `4` instead of `5`.